# python writing jpg files into a new html file

Tags: python, html, file, jpeg

Please can someone help me?

I have been trying to write in an html file that I create myself, a bunch of jpg files just to display them, but I can't seem to do anything, and there have been so many errors till I got even anywhere...
Can anyone please help, I have no experience in html from python.

Here's the code:

```
def download_images(img_urls, dest_dir):
#html_file = open("index.html", 'rb')
html_file = open("index.html", 'w')

print("Retrieving...")
html_file.write("""<verbatim>""")
html_file.write("""<html>""")
html_file.write("""<body>""")

for url,i in zip(img_urls,range(len(img_urls))):
  image_opened = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "img" + str(i) + ".jpg")
  img_tag = r'"""<img"""' + str(i) + r' src="/edu/python/exercises/img' + str(i) + r'"""">"""'.format(urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "img" + str(i) + ".jpg"))
  html_file = open("index.html", 'w')
  html_file.write(urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "img" + str(i) + ".jpg"))
  #print('<img' + str(i) + ' src="/edu/python/exercises/img"' + str(i) + '>')

html_file.write(r""""</body>""""")
html_file.write("""</html>""")
html_file.close()
```

Comment: perhaps you're doing too much of the lifting yourself? [html](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html/1.16)

Comment: I don't understand. There wasn't anything related to jpg writing, only text...

Comment: Can you add an example of the html you are trying to create?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/exercises/log-puzzle?hl=en

Comment: I am doing this exercise and I am just stuck on the html part of part B :/

Comment: Is that the complete content of your program file or is there more? As I can't see where the function is called.

Comment: This is only the function/part for the Part B of the exercise. The full program consists of another function that returns the actual urls from within the  text that was given ( stuff like code.google.com/edu/project/etc...)

Comment: this function takes the list of actual urls and I need it to write inside my "index.html" the jpgs. (The jpgs themselves are accesed as the urlretrive really does make jpg files with the images in them)

Comment: Can you add the errors that you are getting?

Comment: Now I am getting an  "TypeError: must be str, not tuple" error.

Comment: for this line:                                                                                     html_file.write(urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "img" + str(i) + ".jpg"))

Comment: Is there even a way to write an image file into an html? or give it a tag/link for the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go through what you have so far and comment on it.

The first few bits look okay until

```
image_opened = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

This line opens a stream to the requested url, you don't do anything with this and you don't need it as you download the image using:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "img" + str(i) + ".jpg")
```

You then create the html img line, which you have overcomplicated a bit. You are trying to produce a line that reads something like this:

`<img src='img1.jpg' />`

What you seem to be doing in:

```
img_tag = r'"""<img"""' + str(i) + r' src="/edu/python/exercises/img' + str(i) + r'"""">"""'.format(urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "img" + str(i) + ".jpg"))
```

Is starting to create the right string but then you attempt to download the jpg again. You just need to do create the string as follows:

```
img_tag = "<img src='src" + str(i) + ".jpg' />"
```

You then open the html output file again using:

```
html_file = open("index.html", 'w')
```

You don't need to do this as you still have the file open from when you opened it at the beginning of the method.

You then attempt to write the html string to the file doing;

```
html_file.write(urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "img" + str(i) + ".jpg"))
```

This is instead trying to download the jpg again and output the result into the html file. Instead you want to write the `img_tag` by:

```
html_file.write(img_tag)
```

You write the end of the file okay and close it.

```
html_file.write(r""""</body>""""")
html_file.write("""</html>""")
html_file.close()
```

Once you fix this you should have a function that looks like:

```
import urllib.request

def download_images(img_urls, dest_dir):
    #html_file = open("index.html", 'rb')
    html_file = open("index.html", 'w')

    print("Retrieving...")
    html_file.write("<html>")
    html_file.write("<body>")

     for url,i in zip(img_urls,range(len(img_urls))):
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "img" + str(i) + ".jpg") # Downloads image
        img_tag = "<img src='img" + str(i) + ".jpg' />"
        html_file.write(img_tag)

    html_file.write("</body>")
    html_file.write("</html>")
    html_file.close()
```

That you can call with something like:

```
download_images(["a.jpg","b.jpg"],"")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really know nothing on html in python and I think you explained it very well :) Good day.